# How to get date from calendarView() onCreate, with a specific format e.g. DD/MM/YYYY?

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I'm trying to get a date from calendar view:

```
calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
```

by trying:

```
String selectedDate = calendar.getDate().toString();
```

But am getting error saying that `toString()` method can not be resolved
I would like to further get it in a format of "DD/MM/YYYY"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String selectedDate = sdf.format(new Date(calendar.getDate()));
```

Comment: Having issues with new Date(calendar.getDate()) bit, imported import java.util.Date yet am getting an error saying "parse (java.lang.String) in DateFormat can not be applied to (java.util.Date)"